# Left Outer Join (MySQL) Issues, what's wrong with this query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, left-join

I am having five tables in mySQL and i am working on student fees module but i am having some problems on query so i am unable to get appropriate result so please help me I would greatly appreciate it if you kindly give me some feedback on this Query.

1.a )class_details Table Create

```
CREATE TABLE `class_details` 
(`class_id_pk` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
,`class_name`varchar(200) NOT NULL
,`session` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
,`class_status` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY (`class_id_pk`)
,UNIQUE KEY `UNIQUE` (`class_name`,`session`)) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

1.b) class_details Insert

```
insert  into `class_details`
(`class_id_pk`,`class_name`,`session`,`class_status`) 
VALUES 
(1,'1st','2016-2017',NULL)
,(2,'2nd','2016-2017',NULL)
,(3,'3rd','2016-2017',NULL);
```

2.a) feedetails Table Create

```
CREATE TABLE `feedetails` 
(`section_id_fk` int(50) NOT NULL
,`fees` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY (`section_id_fk`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

2.b) feedetails Insert

```
insert  into `feedetails`(`section_id_fk`,`fees`) 
values 
(1,'1000')
,(2,'2000')
,(3,'3000')
,(4,'4000')
,(5,'5000')
,(6,'6000');
```

3.a) section_details Create

```
CREATE TABLE `section_details` 
(`section_id_pk` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
,`class_id_fk` int(11) NOT NULL
,`section_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL
,`section_status` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY (`section_id_pk`,`class_id_fk`,`section_name`)
,UNIQUE KEY `UNIQUE` (`class_id_fk`,`section_name`)
,CONSTRAINT `FK_section_details` FOREIGN KEY (`class_id_fk`) REFERENCES `class_details` (`class_id_pk`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

3.b) section_details Insert

```
insert  into `section_details` (`section_id_pk`,`class_id_fk`,`section_name`,`section_status`) 
values 
(1,1,'A',NULL)
,(2,2,'A',NULL)
,(3,3,'A',NULL);
```

4.a) student_fee

```
CREATE TABLE `student_fee` 
( `sr_no` int(200) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
,`scholar_no`int(50) NOT NULL
,`paid_amount` int(200) DEFAULT NULL
,`due_amount` int(200) DEFAULT NULL
,`fee_date` date DEFAULT NULL
,`section_id_fk` int(50) DEFAULT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY (`sr_no`)
,KEY `FK_student_fee`(`section_id_fk`)
,CONSTRAINT `FK_student_fee` FOREIGN KEY (`section_id_fk`) REFERENCES `section_details` (`section_id_pk`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

4.b) student_fee Insert

```
insert  into student_fee` (`sr_no`,`scholar_no`,`paid_amount`,`due_amount`,`fee_date`,`section_id_fk`) 
values 
(3,5,800,200,'2016-06-16',1)
,(4,29,1000,0,'2016-06-16',1)
,(5,5,200,0,'2016-06-16',1);
```

5.a) student_details Create

```
CREATE TABLE `student_details` 
(`scholar_no` int(30) NOT NULL
,`fname` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL
,`lname` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL
,`stu_class` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL
,`rte` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL
,`active` varbinary(10) DEFAULT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY (`scholar_no`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

5.b) student_details Insert

```
insert  into `student_details` (`scholar_no`,`fname`,`lname`,`stu_class`,`rte`,`active`) 
values 
(5,'KP','PK','1','N','y')
,(29,'Abc','Xyz','1','N','y');
```

Above i have mentioned all the Table details which are used for this query.
First time in student_details table stu_class=1 and the fees will be 1000. when i insert some values in student_fee and use my query then the result is correct but when i insert some of amount to another student in student_fee then the query added the paid amount to the same student which is not correct i want to show the inserted fees for those student who actually inserted..

```
SELECT 
student_details.scholar_no
,student_details.fname
,student_details.lname
,student_details.stu_class
,feedetails.fees
,class_name
,section_name
,IF(sssf.paid_amount IS NULL,0,sssf.paid_amount) AS paid_amount 
FROM 
    (student_details 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN feedetails 
        ON student_details.stu_class = feedetails.section_id_fk
    ) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
    scholar
    , SUM(pa) AS paid_amount
    , SUM(pva) AS prev_paid_amount
    ,SUM(da) AS due_amount
    , SUM(dva) AS prev_due_amount
    ,section_id_fk
    ,fee_date
    ,stu_class 
    FROM 
        (SELECT 
        scholar
        ,CASE WHEN section_id_fk = stu_class THEN paid_amount ELSE 0 END AS pa
        ,CASE WHEN section_id_fk != stu_class THEN paid_amount ELSE 0 END AS pva
        ,CASE WHEN section_id_fk = stu_class THEN due_amount ELSE 0 END AS da
        ,CASE WHEN section_id_fk != stu_class THEN due_amount ELSE 0 END AS dva
        ,due_amount
        ,paid_amount
        ,section_id_fk
        ,fee_date
        ,stu_class 
        FROM 
            (SELECT 
            scholar
            ,due_amount
            ,SUM(paid_amount) AS paid_amount
            ,section_id_fk
            ,fee_date 
            FROM 
                (SELECT 
                student_fee.due_amount AS due_amount
                ,student_fee.paid_amount AS paid_amount
                ,student_fee.scholar_no AS scholar
                ,section_id_fk
                ,fee_date 
                FROM student_fee 
                ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(fee_date,'%Y-%m-%d')DESC
                ) AS kkk 
            GROUP BY kkk.scholar,section_id_fk ORDER BY scholar
        ) AS k 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN student_details sd 
            ON k.scholar = sd.scholar_no
    ) AS lk
) AS sssf 
ON student_details.scholar_no = sssf.scholar 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT * 
    FROM section_details AS sd 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN class_details cd 
        ON sd.class_id_fk = cd.class_id_pk
    ) AS sc 
ON student_details.stu_class = sc.section_id_pk 
WHERE student_details.active = 'y' AND rte = 'N'
```

Comment: I've just formatted your code so that you can read it more easily. Tell me, do you see any problems in the final query?

Comment: an http://sqlfiddle.com/ would help here.

Comment: @RichBenner yeah thank's for it.!

Comment: It's not a problem. It's always a good idea to format your code correctly, it makes mistakes more obvious to spot.

Comment: @RichBenner when i use SQLYog then the query is well formatted by using formate_current_query but i have no idea to write any code inside the stackoverflow.... !

Comment: I've just indented where appropriate. if you want more info on formatting take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: it's really helpful...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen your query and you did a little bit mistake, use `GROUP BY scholar` after `AS lk` in your query or Find `AS lk` and Replace `AS lk GROUP BY scholar` in your query...!

Comment: Yeah exactly you have examined it well...!

Answer (score 4):

Complicated query. And faulty unfortunately.

First of all you can remove all `ORDER BY` clauses from the subqueries. Subqueries simply return unordered sets, so whether or not they contain an `ORDER BY` clause has no effect (apart from giving the DBMS unnecessary work maybe).

The innermost subquery (kkk) has no `WHERE` clause and no `GROUP BY` clause, so you could just as well select from `student_fee` directly.

The next subquery (kk) groups by `scholar` and `section_id_fk`, but you select `due_amount` and `fee_date` without any aggregation. This gives you arbitrarily chosen values. Shouldn't that be `sum(due_amount)` or `max(due_amount)` or the like?

Then in the sssf subquery you have no `GROUP BY` clause. This gives you exactly one result row. But you select unaggregated `scholar`, `section_id_fk`, `fee_date`, `stu_class`, so again you get arbitrarily chosen values, e.g. one of all the scholars.

Check all your aggregations. It might help to set `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode, so as to avoid mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Check the below SQL, I had a quick fix. If does not solve please explain your problem a bit more.

```
SELECT 
student_details.scholar_no
,student_details.fname
,student_details.lname
,student_details.stu_class
,feedetails.fees
,class_name
,section_name
,IF(sssf.paid_amount IS NULL,0,sssf.paid_amount) AS paid_amount 
FROM 
    (student_details 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN feedetails 
        ON student_details.stu_class = feedetails.section_id_fk
    ) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
    scholar
    , SUM(pa) AS paid_amount
    , SUM(pva) AS prev_paid_amount
    ,SUM(da) AS due_amount
    , SUM(dva) AS prev_due_amount
    ,section_id_fk
    ,fee_date
    ,stu_class 
    FROM 
        (SELECT 
        scholar
        ,CASE WHEN section_id_fk = stu_class THEN paid_amount ELSE 0 END AS pa
        ,CASE WHEN section_id_fk != stu_class THEN paid_amount ELSE 0 END AS pva
        ,CASE WHEN section_id_fk = stu_class THEN due_amount ELSE 0 END AS da
        ,CASE WHEN section_id_fk != stu_class THEN due_amount ELSE 0 END AS dva
        ,due_amount
        ,paid_amount
        ,section_id_fk
        ,fee_date
        ,stu_class 
        FROM 
            (SELECT 
            scholar
            ,due_amount
            ,SUM(paid_amount) AS paid_amount
            ,section_id_fk
            ,fee_date 
            FROM 
                (SELECT 
                student_fee.due_amount AS due_amount
                ,student_fee.paid_amount AS paid_amount
                ,student_fee.scholar_no AS scholar
                ,section_id_fk
                ,fee_date 
                FROM student_fee 
                ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(fee_date,'%Y-%m-%d')DESC
                ) AS kkk 
            GROUP BY kkk.scholar,section_id_fk ORDER BY scholar
        ) AS k 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN student_details sd 
            ON k.scholar = sd.scholar_no
    ) AS lk
    group by scholar
) AS sssf 
ON student_details.scholar_no = sssf.scholar 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT * 
    FROM section_details AS sd 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN class_details cd 
        ON sd.class_id_fk = cd.class_id_pk
    ) AS sc 
ON student_details.stu_class = sc.section_id_pk 
WHERE student_details.active = 'y' AND rte = 'N'
```

Comment: A Big Thank's to @ghkhan, yeah it's working now as per the requirement. i can see here that i have done a silly mistake here #group by scholar is the key.. thank's man

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT 
student_details.scholar_no
,student_details.fname
,student_details.lname
,student_details.stu_class
,feedetails.fees
,class_name
,section_name
,IF(sssf.paid_amount IS NULL,0,sssf.paid_amount) AS paid_amount 
FROM 
    (student_details 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN feedetails 
        ON student_details.stu_class = feedetails.section_id_fk
    ) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
    scholar
    ,pa AS paid_amount
    ,pva AS prev_paid_amount
    ,da AS due_amount
    ,dva AS prev_due_amount
    ,section_id_fk
    ,fee_date
    ,stu_class 
    FROM 
        (SELECT 
        scholar
        ,CASE WHEN section_id_fk = stu_class THEN paid_amount ELSE 0 END AS pa
        ,CASE WHEN section_id_fk != stu_class THEN paid_amount ELSE 0 END AS pva
        ,CASE WHEN section_id_fk = stu_class THEN due_amount ELSE 0 END AS da
        ,CASE WHEN section_id_fk != stu_class THEN due_amount ELSE 0 END AS dva
        ,due_amount
        ,paid_amount
        ,section_id_fk
        ,fee_date
        ,stu_class 
        FROM 
            (SELECT 
            scholar
            ,due_amount
            ,paid_amount AS paid_amount
            ,section_id_fk
            ,fee_date 
            FROM 
                (SELECT 
    student_fee.due_amount AS due_amount,SUM(student_fee.paid_amount) AS paid_amount,student_fee.scholar_no AS scholar,section_id_fk,fee_date 
    FROM student_fee  GROUP BY scholar 
                ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(fee_date,'%Y-%m-%d')DESC
                ) AS kkk 
             ORDER BY scholar
        ) AS k 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN student_details sd 
            ON k.scholar = sd.scholar_no
    ) AS lk
) AS sssf 
ON student_details.scholar_no = sssf.scholar 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT * 
    FROM section_details AS sd 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN class_details cd 
        ON sd.class_id_fk = cd.class_id_pk
    ) AS sc 
ON student_details.stu_class = sc.section_id_pk 
WHERE student_details.active = 'y' AND rte = 'N'
```

Comment: thank's for your effort but in your case the paid_amount is showing 0 even i have insert some amount for paid amount.. look at the above query which is working... !